# How to get user id from message to which I replied with Telebot?

Tags: python

How do I get by using the user id bot on which I replied in the chat?
I tried to do so

```
give_id = message.reply_to_message.from_user.id
```

But an error appears

```
give_id = message.reply_to_message.from_user.id 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_user'
```

Comment: That error tells you message.reply_to_message is None. If you show more code it would be easier to explain why is None at that point.

Comment: I found a solution by making the group a supergroup